# How do solve this error? AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, attributes, tuples, strip

I keep getting this attribute error when running this code:

```
firstName = input('Enter First Name: \n')
middleName = input('Enter Middle Name: \n')
lastName = input('Enter Last Name: \n')


print(((lastName, ',', firstName[0],'.', middleName[0], '.').strip()))
```

I understand that the compiler thinks I made a tuple but that wasn't my intention. I solely want to print out lastName, first name initial, middle name initial in that exact format.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `strip()`?

Comment: As in the Error message, you can't use `.strip()` in tuple. You should use `.strip()` in `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`, separately if that's what you want